# How to avoid certificate verification issues?

Tags: ssl, mercurial

I'm trying to push to a Bitbucket Mercurial repository but I keep hitting the same problem:

```
ruihpacheco at descartes in ~/chi/aaa/cpp/ninja (default)
$ hg push
pushing to https://rhpacheco@bitbucket.org/rhpacheco/databaseclient
abort: error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)
```

I've already tried what's on the [website](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CACertificates#Mac_OS_X_10.6_and_higher) but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this in your **.hgrc** file:

```
[hostsecurity]
bitbucket.org:fingerprints = sha1:3F:D3:C5:17:23:3C:CD:F5:2D:17:76:06:93:7E:EE:97:42:21:14:AA
```

Do you get the same error?

Comment: Where did you get that fingerprint?

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work: abort: invalid fingerprint for bitbucket.org: sh1:3F:D3:C5:17:23:3C:CD:F5:2D:17:76:06:93:7E:EE:97:42:21:14:AA
(must begin with "sha1:", "sha256:", or "sha512:")

Comment: Sorry, missed the "a" in "sha1". Fixed the fingerprint in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got sha256 fingerprint from Chrome developers tools, security tab. And it works.